# Securing a web session for an embedded page

Tags: html, authentication, iframe, jwt, single-page-application

We've got a single page web application  that needs to be hosted within another web page via an iframe.

This third party web application, that we have no control over (i.e. not written or hosted by us), launches our application via a customised endpoint that we will provide, which expects to receive encrypted launch parameters that provide the context of who the end-user is, along with their role.  The encryption is done by the embedding app via a shared secret, so we can decrypt the request, validate it (it contains a time limiting parameter) and launch our application with the correct user permissions.

Once launched our application is a SPA so the iframe itself is never reloaded, but there are calls back to our app endpoints to manipulate data.  These endpoints are secured using JWT tokens which would normally be provided by the authorization header of a user that had logged in via the normal UI launch page.

In the case of this embedded use, there is no JWT so we need to figure out how to secure access to the data endpoints.

I can see (at least) two ways:

- get our app to request a JWT from an IdP that gets sent back with the embedded app so the browser will attach it to subsequent calls. This has the advantge that existing data endpoints will work with no change.
- change our auth layer so that it can uses the session, or the JWT, to control access. This will require a change to the authentication/authorisation layer of our app.

I'm not sure of the technicalities of either solution, so am checking in here first before I proceed to more detailed investigation/design.

Note that we have to use this unusual embedding mechanism, as the third party app is dominant in the market space we operate in. My preference would be for them to pass us the token - but they do not use tokens for their auth.